# Socket.IO - Huawei Error de conexión

Tags: android, socket.io

He estado utilizado [com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) en las aplicaciones Android para conectarme a un servidor que me proporciona información en tiempo real, pero recientemente tuve un inconveniente con un equipo de la marca Huawei, en el cual no funciona esta librería. Noté que es debido a que el puerto que utilizo en el servidor es diferente al por defecto de socket.io y por lo tanto lo debo especificar de la siguiente forma:

```html
private Socket mSocket;
{
  try {
    mSocket = IO.socket("http://dominio-servidor:2040");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

De esta forma me funciona en celulares de otras marcas como Samsung, LG, entre otros, pero con dispositivos Huawei no logro que se realice la conexión, tampoco se dispara el catch para ver el error. (Solo sucede cuando debo especificarle un puerto de conexión al servidor).

Alguien ha tenido este mismo inconveniente?

Answer (score 0):

Luego de hacer varias pruebas, encontré que no eran los dispositivos Huawei, sino la versión 9 de Android. Esta es la respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284903/socket-io-not-working-on-android-9-api-level-28